# Exporting data from a sparkR job

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I have an R script similar to the example one, where you load some
data from hdfs and then store it somehow, in this case via Parquet
file.

```
library(SparkR)

# Initialize SparkContext and SQLContext
sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

# Create a simple local data.frame
localDF <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Smith", "Sarah"), age=c(19, 23, 18))

# Create a DataFrame from a JSON file
peopleDF <- jsonFile(sqlContext, file.path("/people.json"))

# Register this DataFrame as a table.
registerTempTable(peopleDF, "people")

# SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext
teenagers <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")

# Store the teenagers in a table
saveAsParquetFile(teenagers, file.path("/teenagers"))

# Stop the SparkContext now
sparkR.stop()
```

How exactly do I retrieve the data from the cluster into another spark
application? I'm currently considering connecting to the hdfs master
and retrieving the files according to [this
example](https://github.com/adobe-research/spark-parquet-thrift-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/SparkParquetThriftApp.scala),
except for replacing the sbt-thrift with
[scrooge](https://twitter.github.io/scrooge/).

Is there a more idiomatic way to retrieve the data without a direct
connection to the hadoop cluster? I considered copying the data out of
the hdfs, but parquet can only read from hadoop from what I've
understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a `SparkContext` with master `local` and use `SparkSQL` to retrieve the data.